# How do you replicate a changing pointer with C++ smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

```
struct A {
   int val;
};
struct B {
    int val2;
    A* ptr = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    A a1, a2;
    B b;
    if (...) { B.ptr = &a1; } else { B.ptr = &a2; }
    return 0;
}
```

How can ptr be represented with a smart ptr? It doesn't own but needs to access the objects a1 and a2. B 'uses' only one of a1 or a2, which later may toggle.

Changing ptr doesn't mean a1 or a2 should be deleted ofcourse. So, unique_ptr.reset() is not a solution.

Comment: What sort of "smarts" do you need? Usually smart pointers are used to manage ownership and lifetime, which isn't an issue here.

Comment: If it doesn't own the pointer then just use the raw pointer, no smarts needed.

Comment: What is the problem you encounter when using a smart pointer instead of `A*` anyway?

Comment: Galik's comment is already the right answer. For the future, C++17 will offer `observer_ptr` to use in these situations, which helps to make the intended use of the pointer clearer (and also avoids calling `delete` on it by mistake).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you don't need a smart pointer in order to delete a1 or a2.

So it would seem that a smart pointer is not needed at all...

Unless you wanted some special cleanup code to be executed on only one of the objects when b goes out of scope.

In which case it would look something like this:

```
struct A {
   int val = 0;
};

struct cleanup_A {
  void operator()(A* pa) const {
    if (pa) { my_cleanup_action(*pa); }
  }
};

struct B {
  using special_A_ptr = std::unique_ptr<A, cleanup_A>;
  int val2 = 0;
  special_A_ptr ptr = { nullptr, cleanup_A() };
};

int main() {
  A a1,a2;
  B b;
  if (...) { b.ptr.reset(&a1); } else { b.ptr.reset(&a2); }
  return 0;
}
```

Of course in such cases of non-standard use, all the usual warnings apply...